# What pattern for Doing a task with a thread and do some action latter

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

What I´m doing:

- Have a application with player
- The user press the "Play button", "Download the file" or "Play and Download the file"
- It fires a thread to Download the file.

I'm developing with C++ with MFC, and the thread cannot access the internals easily. I can just pass the HI/LOWWORD.

When the thread finishes, and it come back to the main thread, how can I signal what action the thread should make?
Actually I pass in the thread construction the action, like:

Calling: `StartThread(file, PLAY);`

The end of the thread: `pClass->SendMessage(WM_DOWNLOADVIDEOTHREADEND,(WPARAM)downloadedfile,ACTION);`

And then when the application receives the **DOWNLOADVIDEOTHREADEND** message, it check the **ACTION** and do it.

But it do not look elegant, it a mess!

There some pattern for this?

There´s a better way to do this?

Comment: MFC is nowhere from elegant. If this is not a requirement, you have other options: use Qt if you do C++, or switch to .NET and use WPF or Windows Forms with eg. C#.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, but MFC is a requirement, its a big legacy project.

Comment: Use PostMessage(), SendMessage() won't marshal to the correct thread.  This is the underlying core of all thread marshaling wrappers.  How usable they'll be has a lot to do with keeping up on releases.  Usually a problem with shops that are stuck in legacy code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492819.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should split the UI part of your application with your logic part in the different modules. Let's say that you wrote an module with a name player you have to provide an interface for the player listener such as Java's swing do it for the buttons. After that you can catch your events everywhere independent of technology you using ( QT, MFC , VCL and so on). So you could implement the bridge, strategy or observer pattern in this case. I will give you an example with a bridge design patter:

```
class Player{
private:
  IPlayerListener* _listener;

private:
  static void threadCallback( void* arg ){
     Player* player = (Player*)arg;
     //Download file here
     player._listener->downloadComplete( track );
  }

public:
  Player( IPlayerListener* listener ){
    _listener = listener;
  }

  bool playFile( uri file ){
    //Start a new thread and do all staff needed to download the file in there.
    thread.start(threadCallback, this);
  }
};
```

In your interface declare all types of events which player can throw:

```
class IPlayerListener{
public:
 //...
 virtual void downloadComplete( const string& track )=0;
 //...
};
```

Avoid using libraries like MFC in your project, because it may generate some troubles in 
future. You could move to the other platform or make the decision to use another lib like QT for your GUI.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Very often a main thread in an application will spend most of its time waiting for events to happen with WaitForMultipleObjects(), and then doing something when it comes out of that with notification that an event has happened.

If you treat the result of CreateThread() as another thing to wait for in WaitForMultipleObjects(), it will show up as event when the thread terminates, so you can treat this event just like any other - see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Alternatively, a general way to hide complex waits is to create a thread whose job is to do nothing else but wait for some class of events, and present a more user-friendly interface to them to the rest of the program.

If you are fed up with MFC and know of a better interface design, you do have the option of writing an wrapper in MFC and presents that interface design, or something like it, to the rest of the program.